# Sql serverrRecursive query for BOM not showing child parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have three tables:

1. SO_Items Sales orders - SOCTE lists all Parts that have live sales orders
2. Components - links a part with it's component part ( this can be several layers deep ). CR lists all parts and it's components using recursion.
3. WO Works orders - WOCTE lists all Parts that have active sales orders and their respective work order.

The problem I have is:

I have a sales order for Part 100831 which is made from 100831-U.
I have a works order number  10 for 100831 and 11 for 100831-U.

The result of my query is:

```
Part     WO
100831   10
100831-U 11
```

which is correct.

But I would like it to be

```
Part   WO
100831 10
100831 11
```

I only want the Part with the sales order listed with all its and its components works orders.
I have tried using variables but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I have created a SQL fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c77a5/1

The current output is:

```
|      PART | WO |
|-----------|----|
|    100831 | 10 |
|  100831-U | 11 |
|    106061 | 12 |
|     43567 | 15 |
| R106061-1 | 13 |
| R106061-1 | 14 |
```

and I am trying to get just the Parts in SO_Items (sales orders) with all the WO_No (work order numbers) that are in it's BOM. (Bill of materials)

```
|      PART | WO |
|-----------|----|
|    100831 | 10 |
|    100831 | 11 |
|    106061 | 12 |
|     43567 | 15 |
|    106061 | 13 |
|    106061 | 14 |

WITH SOCTE (Part) as
(
SELECT DISTINCT SO_Items.Part_No
FROM  SO_Items
WHERE (SO_Items.Fully_Del='N') 
),

CR (Part,Component) as
(
SELECT  SOCTE.Part , Components.Component_Part_No 
FROM Components
JOIN SOCTE 
ON Components.Parent_Part_No = SOCTE.Part
UNION ALL
SELECT Parent_Part_No,Component_Part_No 
FROM Components
INNER JOIN CR AS SCR ON SCR.Component = Components.Parent_Part_No
),

WOCTE(Part,WO) as 
(
Select  Distinct Part ,WO.WO_No
FROM  WO 
Inner JOIN CR 
ON CR.Part=WO.Part_No and WO.WO_Complete=0 and   WO.ReProcess=0
)
SELECT Part,WO FROM WOCTE
Order by Part
```

Comment: You just want to strip off everything after the dash in the `Part` field?  Why not `LEFT(Part,CHARINDEX('-',Part)-1)`?

Comment: This is an example. The component of  a part could be any other part.

Comment: Then don't you want `WOCTE` to select `CR.Component` instead of or in addition to `CR.Part`?  Or possibly `SELECT CR.Part, WO.WO_No ... UNION SELECT CR.Component, WO.WO_No ...`?  It would help if "I only want the Part with the sales order listed with all its and its components works orders." were a complete and concrete sentence.

Comment: You are correct in saying that I need  select CR.Part, WO.WO_NO ... Union select CR.Component,Wo_Wo_No to get all works orders from the part and all it's components. However the last part in the hierarchy is always raw material and will never have a works order (WO.WO_No).

Comment: `WO RIGHT JOIN CR` in `WOCTE`?

Comment: WO RIGHT JOIN CR in WOCTE has no effect. This still leaves me with the problem of how to select a part (which has a sales order) from SOCTE , all its works orders (WO.WO_No) and all the works orders of its components. In the format that only has the part number from SOCTE. i.e. the component parts from my query results are substituted with the part number from the  sales order (SOCTE) table.  Does this make sense to you? I'm not sure that I have explained this very well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your updated explanation helped a lot.

I think I have it:

```
;WITH SOCTE (Part) as (
    SELECT DISTINCT SO_Items.Part_No
    FROM  SO_Items
    WHERE (SO_Items.Fully_Del = 'N') 
),
CR (Part, SO_Part, Component, Step) as (
    SELECT SOCTE.Part, SOCTE.Part AS "SO_Part", Components.Component_Part_No, 0
    FROM Components
    JOIN SOCTE 
        ON Components.Parent_Part_No = SOCTE.Part

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Components.Parent_Part_No, SCR.SO_Part, Components.Component_Part_No, SCR.Step + 1
    FROM Components
    INNER JOIN CR AS SCR 
        ON SCR.Component = Components.Parent_Part_No
),
WOCTE (Part, WO) as (
    SELECT DISTINCT CR.SO_Part, WO.WO_No
    FROM WO 
    INNER JOIN CR 
        ON  CR.Part        = WO.Part_No 
        AND WO.WO_Complete = 0
        AND WO.ReProcess   = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM WOCTE
ORDER BY Part
```

It's not perfect and I have extra fields in there.  I decided that if you couldn't make one field do two things, then maybe there should be a second field.  The `Step` field is just to see how the CTE is recursing.  Using `SELECT * FROM CR` with the step numbers helped to see where the fields were going and what I needed to preserve.

Comment: Thank you Bacon Bits it worked perfectly. I was going round in circles trying to solve this.